# Marketplace offers downloads in notifications but when I tap notification none are available

Tags: google-play-store, updates

I've seen some other places with this question, but no answers that explain/help with what's going on.

I've got a Droid 3, and about once a day I get a notification that there are updates available for my apps. When I tap the notification to be taken to the market place; however, there are either no apps to update or the wrong number of apps (i.e. notification says 2, only one app is available).

Does anyone know why this is happening or if there's a way to resolve it?

Comment: Do you have multiple accounts tied to the Market app?

Comment: Another possible issue is that the app you are being alerted to is set to auto-update, so that by the time you notice the alert the app has already updated.

Comment: Are you referring to the Amazon-Appstore, not the Android Market? I have the same problem on my Xoom and Droid 3 with the Amazon-Appstore. From what I can tell is that it may be an update alert for one of the Apps that I have tied to my account, but not installed on my device.

Comment: I have this same problem with the Android Market. I have a Nexus One, 2.3.6, and it is not due to auto-updating apps as there is no report of download or installation.

Comment: No multiple accounts, no auto-updates conflicting things. The Android Market, not Amazon App Store. I do have multiple devices so I think the answers below about getting update notices for apps not on a particular device is likely.

Answer (score 4):

If you have multiple Google accounts setup, click menu, then accounts, to make sure the proper account is selected. Then click menu, then my apps.

Comment: I don't have multiple accounts - but a good answer for those who do!

Answer (score 2):

I have noticed that having multiple android devices can trigger my update notifications. I, of course, use the same account for both devices but when updates are available on one, they are not aways available on both. I'll typically get a notification on both devices.

Comment: Potentially the same issue as in my answer.  +1 for another explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You could try clearing the cache/data for the Market app.

Settings->Applications->Market, select the Market app, then click the "clear data" button. (You may need to force stop the market app first)

Answer (score 1):

This is a little bug with something in the marketplace.  The way i have fixed it is by uninstalling the updates for the market.   Just go to settings - applications - manage applications - go to market and select uninstall updates.  Launch the market, it will be a much older version.  Give your phone about 30 minutes and the market will update to the newest version and you will no longer have the update notification issue.

Answer (score 1):

This could potentially be caused by having an app that has been restricted since you downloaded it.  If it's no longer available for your device / network / location then it won't show up in the Market, but it's possible that the Market still checks to see if a newer version is available.  I believe I had this issue back with the v2.x Market, but not since I uninstalled the app in question.

Comment: notification for restricted apps or location-locked apps don't show.. I confirmed it on my Android Market 3.3.11

Answer (score 0):

Did your phone come with some apps pre-installed on it? That can sometimes cause issues with the update process. Pre-installed apps are often placed in the system directory and the market might not properly update them. If you can, see if the apps that are listed as updatable are pre-installed.

Another potential issue is a mismatched signing key. It's more common if you install development versions of apps, but an app that is signed with a key that doesn't match the market version cannot be updated.

Answer (score -1):

The latest version of the Market will automatically update apps that you have allowed to auto-update. The checkmark notification will disappear from the notification area immediately after the update.

Those apps that aren't allowed to auto-update will be unupdated so when you go to the market those will be left unupdated.

Comment: It's not clear to me that this answers the question.  If the checkmark disappears for updated apps, and remains only for un-updated apps, the counter should be consistent.  But the OP says that it is not consistent.

Comment: I know I have the same condition on my phone as he describes. I assumed it was because some of the apps had already been auto-updated while others were not. I don't think there's anyway for the notification to change the number of apps to be updated to reflect those that auto-installed as that installation occurs AFTER the notification is generated.